# Fix "Nickname is already in use" in my Python IRC client

Tags: python, irc

Error:

```
NOTICE Auth :*** Looking up your hostname...
433 * testbot:Nickname is already in use.
NOTICE Auth :*** Could not resolve your hostname: Request timed out; using your IP address () instead.
451 837AAAABB JOIN :You have not registered
```

The script works fine, the only issue I'm having is when another user has the same name and so the bot won't join, how can I fix this?

```
#IRC Info, Where the bot connects too
server="Server"
botnick="testbot"
channel="#test"
```

What I have tried:

Google, YouTube, Looking at other github IRC bot's and stackoverflow.

One idea I had was to use an random string generator, so if the name "testbot" was taken the script would generator something random and try again. I'm unsure how I would add this.

Comment: Maybe you're connecting twice, or maybe you're using a reserved name.

Comment: Generally, you try another nickname in order to connect. The bot should also be registered with NickServ (available on most networks) so that it can reclaim the nickname and then switch to it.

Comment: Hello,
You're both correct, however, I don't want to change it manually, I want the script to automatic do it.
That's why I was thinking of using a random string so the names would always be random and not be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help you without seeing some **code** that you tried. Or any code at all.

The overall idea would be to detect when an incoming message is a `433` (aka `ERR_NICKNAMEINUSE`), and then send a new `NICK` command with a new nickname; and try again until you find a free nickname.

Pseudocode:

```
MAINNICK = 'testbot'
nick_suffix = 1
send_msg('NICK {}'.format(MAINNICK))
while True:
    msg = recv_msg()
    if msg.split(' ')[1] == '433':
        send_msg('NICK {}{}'.format(MAINNICK, nick_suffix))
        nick_suffix += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the nick is registered by you.

When receiving [`ERR_NICKNAMEINUSE (433)`](https://modern.ircdocs.horse/#errnicknameinuse-433), send `REGAIN` to `nickserv`. Personally I also take care to not send `REGAIN` more than 3 times in 30 seconds, otherwise I disconnect and reconnect because something else is wrong.

```
REGAIN YourRegisteredNick YourPassword
```

Once in a while, `NOTICE` with a second argument containing `can not regain your nickname` is then received. This indicates a `REGAIN` failure. The only way I am aware of to handle this error is to disconnect, reconnect, and rejoin channels.

Answer (score 0):

`irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
def ircwrite(message):
global irc
irc.send(str(message).encode('utf-8'))
botnick = "ME_Number-1" # Nickname of the bot
InUse_alt = "Me2" # if Nickname: "('botnick')" is already in use, A.K.A. 433, uses this alternative option instead
while 1:
text = irc.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
print(text)
    if "433" in text:
        print("Bot's nick IN USE or has been regged by another; switching to: "+ (InUse_alt))
    if text.find("433") != -1:
        ircwrite("NICK "+ InUse_alt +" \r\n")`


---
Something like that would work in most situations, but it can be set off by: someone saying: "433"; trying to work on that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Send **one nick** but not **both nick1 and nick2**. To send new nick2

```
send_msg(f'NICK {}'.format(nick2_suffix))
```

In my case:

```
socket.socket.send(f'NICK {NICK2}')
```

Another way. In entry box.

```
/NICK NICK2
```